# How to show the visual representation of parse tree generated by Antlr in vscode

Tags: angular, typescript, antlr

we are using parser,lexer etc which is generated by our backend team for typescript we are using them in our angular applications to generate a parse. we are able to generate the parse tree and print that tree to console but we struggling in printing its visual representation of the parse tree.
below is the sample code used to generate the parse tree

```
let code: string = `
        begin rule "My rule"
        doc := input.document_id
        ref := input.refrence
        countryuppper := upper(doc.country)
        country := doc.country
        end rule
    `;
this.inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream(code);
this.lexer = new Lexer(this.inputStream);
this.tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(this.lexer);
this.parser = new Parser(this.tokenStream);
this.tree = this.parser.program();
console.log(this.tree)
```

visual representation I mean is like in the below image
[image]

Could anyone please tell us how can we print the visual representation of the parse tree in vscode.

Comment: What is "the visual representation"? The Lisp-like string representation? If you want to get a visual (UML like) representation, then the answer is: you cannot do that using ANTLR. You will need other tools/libraries to do that.

Comment: Hi Bart Kiers I have added the image the of how I want to print the tree

Comment: OK, then the answer is that it is not possible using ANTLR. You can only do that with some external tool or library. If your follow up question is "what can I use for that?", then that question is off-topic on stackoverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (especially the part: "Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be closed by the community until they are improved."). My advice is to try to create it yourself and only ask specific programming related questions here. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Brat Kiers